# restrict past dates in lightning:input

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have as follows:

```
<aura:attribute name="todayDate" type="Date"/>
<lightning:input type="dateTime" aura:id="dat" label="Follow Up" min="{!v.todayDate}"/>
```

In the doInit event of the component I have as follows

```
component.set("v.todayDate",new Date());
```

But when the component loads user is able to select past dates also. Pls let me know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

in your doInit function you have to set today date by using localization service for `todayDate` attribute.

like below
**cmp**

```
 <aura:attribute name="todayDate" type="DateTime"/>
```

**controller.js**

```
 var timezone = $A.get("$Locale.timezone");
    var datetimestring =  new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: timezone}),
       datetime = new Date(datetimestring);
      datetime.setHours(datetime.getHours()+1);
    
    component.set('v.todayDate', datetime);
```

above solution works for me until `summer20`, after seen your comment i checked my project components all of them are broke. after all analysis what i found in [`summer20`](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_aura_components.htm)  release notes again. there is changes for `lightning:input type=Date/datetime`

> **The input types date and datetime have changed.**
>
> 1.On the current month view of the date picker, you can now select a
> date from the previous and next month. Previously, dates from the
> previous and next month were disabled on the current month view unless
> you navigated directly to those months.
>
> 2.When you specify min and max values, users can still select a date outside of the min and max range. However, the blur event triggers the field to display a  validation error message.
>
> 3.The names for months and weekdays in the date picker now use your Salesforce language setting. Previously, these names used your locale setting.

so in your case 2 point applied. that's why past dates are not disable. instead it giving the error.
[image]

Comment: it is still showing the previous dates.

Comment: added updates with changes

Comment: so salesforce upgrade is the issue , I have written a validation to handle this ,thanks for letting me know...

Comment: u don't need to write separate validation. if u set min/max it's fire automatically

Comment: ok, ys I understood..